# join with conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to join tables that contain: Radical , notation, date and year. sometimes the radical and year in table1 are the same than the table2. so my join should respect this three conditions:

1) If radical of tab1= radical of tab2 and years are different join both

2) If radical of tab1 = radical of tab2 and year of tab1=year of tab2 and note of tab1 = note of tab2, keep one copy without duplicate.

3) If radical of tab1 = radical of tab2 and year of tab1=year of tab2 and note of tab1 different from note of tab2 copy the one where date is more recent for example keep 01/12/2015 instead of 01/10/2015

here is an example of the data:

first table

RADICAL NOTE YEAR   DATE

```
5466    A   2014  01/10/2014

5309    B   2014  01/10/2014

1245    A   2015  01/10/2015

9084    D   2013  01/10/2013

5849    E   2012  01/10/2012

2344    C   2016  01/10/2016

5466    D   2016  01/10/2016
```

second table

```
5466    A   2014   01/10/2014

5309    C   2015   01/10/2015

1245    D   2015   01/12/2015

9084    D   2013  01/10/2013

5849    E   2015  01/10/2015

2344    C   2016  01/10/2016

5849    E   2015  01/10/2015
```

RESULT

```
5466    A   2014    01/10/2014


5309    C   2015    01/10/2015

5309    B   2014    01/10/2014

1245    D   2015    01/12/2015

9084    D   2013    01/10/2013

5849    E   2015    01/10/2015

5849    E   2012    01/10/2012

2344    C   2016    01/10/2016

5466    D   2016    01/10/2016
```

this is just an example of two tables, I might have around 8tables to join with the same condition .
The query attempt :

`Select *

from tab (
if tab.RADICAL=tab2.RADICAL and tab.year=tab2.year and tab.note!=tab2.note 
else 
  if tab.Radical=tab2.Radical and tab.year!=tab2.year 
  else
  if tab.Radical=tab2.Radical and tab.year=tab2.year and tab.note=tab2.note keep top date )
   then full outer join tab2`

Any help would be much appreciated.

*Sample data in a consumable format for other users:*

```
CREATE TABLE #Radical1 (Radical smallint,
                        Note char(1),
                        [Year] smallint,
                        [Date] date);

CREATE TABLE #Radical2 (Radical smallint,
                        Note char(1),
                        [Year] smallint,
                        [Date] date);

INSERT INTO #Radical1
VALUES (5466,'A',2014,'20141001'),
       (5309,'B',2014,'20141001'),
       (1245,'A',2015,'20151001'),
       (9084,'D',2013,'20131001'),
       (5849,'E',2012,'20121001'),
       (2344,'C',2016,'20161001'),
       (5466,'D',2016,'20161001');

INSERT INTO #Radical2
VALUES (5466,'A',2014,'20141001'),
       (5309,'C',2015,'20151001'),
       (1245,'D',2015,'20151001'),
       (9084,'D',2013,'20131001'),
       (5849,'E',2015,'20151001'),
       (2344,'C',2016,'20161001'),
       (5849,'E',2015,'20151001');

GO

DROP TABLE #Radical1;
DROP TABLE #Radical2;
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh i'm using MS SQL Server Management studio

Comment: @Maha Management Studio (SSMS) isn't a RDBMS, it's user application used to interact with SQL Server. Examples of SQL Server Versions and Editions would be: `SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition`, `SQL Server 2016 Enterprise Edition`, and `SQL Server 2017 Express` (not an exhaustive list by far).

Comment: Specify the expected result as well, with the table data as above. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Column headings would be nice. You reference fields such as `[note]` and `[Year]` and, although we might be able to surmise which ones these are, it's far better that you actually tell us.

Comment: @Larnu I've edited it

Comment: @jarlh i've put the results

Comment: And what you've attempted so far?

Comment: Remove all those empty rows to make it easier for us to read.

Comment: @jarlh sorry i'm still new here so idk how does it work

Comment: @Larnu i've put the query attempted but it does not work

Comment: You're mixing Logical syntax(`IF`), query syntax and trying to do only do a `JOIN` based on that logic. There's a lot wrong with that query.

Comment: I've added Consumable data for everyone, @jarlh .

Comment: @jarhl didn't add that sample data...

Answer (score 0):

I **think** this is what you're after. The logic you defined, honestly, made no sense, so I worked solely off your expected result set. it matches, but I have no idea if it actually works for the broader data.

```
--Expected results
SELECT Radical, Note,
       [Year],
       CONVERT(date, [date]) AS [Date] --Please consider better names for your columns.
FROM (VALUES(5466,'A',2014,'20141001'),
            (5309,'C',2015,'20151001'),
            (5309,'B',2014,'20141001'),
            (1245,'D',2015,'20151001'),
            (9084,'D',2013,'20131001'),
            (5849,'E',2015,'20151001'),
            (5849,'E',2012,'20121001'),
            (2344,'C',2016,'20161001'),
            (5466,'D',2016,'20161001')) V(Radical, Note, [Year], [Date])
ORDER BY [Date], Radical, Note;
--Results
WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT ISNULL(R2.Radical,R1.Radical) AS Radical,
           ISNULL(R2.Note,R1.Note) AS Note,
           ISNULL(R2.[Year],R1.[Year]) AS [Year],
           ISNULL(R2.[Date],R1.[Date]) AS [Date],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ISNULL(R2.Radical,R1.Radical), ISNULL(R2.[Year],R1.[Year])
                              ORDER BY ISNULL(R2.[Date],R1.[Date]) DESC) AS RN
    FROM #Radical1 R1
         FULL OUTER JOIN #Radical2 R2 ON R1.Radical = R2.Radical
                                     AND R1.[Year] = R2.[Year])
SELECT Radical,
       Note,
       [Year],
       [Date]
FROM RNs
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY [Date], Radical, Note;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you do not need `join`. But it depends on your datas. Especially that are in `Date` column. `Union` can take care of first two conditions. This query returns your expected output

```
select
    top 1 with ties *
from (
    select * from #Radical1
    union
    select * from #Radical2
) t
order by row_number() over (partition by Radical, Year order by Date desc)
```